# .NET / COM events interoperability

Tags: c#, .net, com, interop, com-interop

I have an interop assembly generated by TlbImp.exe, the generated classes are heavily evented and the performance is very important.

But there's a problem, the events seem to be registered/unregistered/invoked in such a manner that even empty event handlers are counted in.
Given a set of **1..N** events, when you register a handler to an event 3 it looks like this:

```
{dummy1, dummy2, eventHandler3, dummy4 ... dummyN}
```

Which generates a large overhead when there's a lot of events that get raised very often.

So the question is, is there a better way how to work with COM events in .NET? Any tool or something or do I have to rewrite the event code of the interop assembly from scratch?

Comment: Can you provide code samples for us to reproduce the issue on our machines?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by using custom `Advise`/`Unadvise` callbakcs.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just allow .NET to build the interop by doing a Using statement?

No events should be invoked unless you explicitly set them.

Example:

http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/SEHE

As you can see the above example sets many events.

Comment: That calls TlbImp.exe for you. And that way is very slow since it creates SinkHelper for each type that defines events.